# Simple, yet efficient PHP Calendar

Tags: php

I need to have a calendar to use at a website, the thing is, that weekends shouldn't show up, and for each month, having different days,

I wrote a basic function, that has many flaws:

```
<?php

function marcardia () {
$meses = Array(1 => 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
echo "<Select>";
foreach ($meses as $key => $mes){
echo "<option>".$meses[$key]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$dias = range(1,40);
echo "<Select>";
foreach ($dias as $key => $dia){
echo "<option>".$dias[$key]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}

marcardia ();

?>


</p>
<p>Marque uma Hora<br/>
<?php

$horas=array(1 => '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00');
$horaz = array();
echo '<select name="hora">';
foreach($horas as $key => $hora){

echo "<option value=\" $hora \"";
echo ">$hora</option> \n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

I am in the process of learning PHP...

Comment: I suggest writhing your code in english, so everybody could understand it easier. For your problem - you can't have select-boxes with suitable days for selected months with php-only. You need javascript which sets up your day-`select` each time the user changes selection in the month-`select`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PEAR's Calendar package](http://pear.php.net/package/Calendar). It's customizable and should be suitable for you.